# получить путь относительно корня для подключаемого файла

Tags: php, replace

Требуется получить не абсолютный путь подключаемого файла, а относительный, например, `/dir/functions.php` вместо `/home/user/htdocs/dir/functions.php`
Т.е. если функция используется в каком-то файле я должен знать из какого файла она подключалась с помощью `include` или `require`.

`__FILE__` хороша тем, что если используется внутри подключаемого файла, то возвращается имя данного файла. То есть при вызове `myFunc(__FILE__)` в файле `index.php` функция `myFunc` возвратит полный путь файла (допустим `functions.php`) из которого она включалась с помощью `include()`.

Реализовал с помощью `str_replace()`, но, быть может, есть что-то более подходящее, о чем мне неизвестно, например, как `dirname(__FILE__)`, которая выполняет противоположную задачу той, которая требуется.

```
<?
    echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', __FILE__);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Порой можно такого нагородить, а потом вспоминаешь, что есть банальный explode() :)

```html
//$tmp = array_reverse(explode('\\', __DIR__)); // на всякий случай для windows разделителей
$tmp = array_reverse(explode('/', __DIR__));
$path = $tmp[0] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename(__FILE__);
print_r($path);
```